# jquery function in jquery-ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I try use jquery function in dialog window. Function is assigned to class ".numeric". When I add class to html input then it works fine, but does not work in the dialog.

```js
// numeric function
!function($){$.fn.alphanumeric=function(p){var input=$(this),az="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzążśźćłóę",options=$.extend({ichars:"!@#$%^&*()+=[]\\';,/{}|\":<>?~`.- _",nchars:"",allow:"",limit:0,counter:""},p),s=options.allow.split(""),i=0,ch,regex;for(i;i<s.length;i++)-1!=options.ichars.indexOf(s[i])&&(s[i]="\\"+s[i]);if(options.nocaps&&(options.nchars+=az.toUpperCase()),options.allcaps&&(options.nchars+=az),options.limit&&options.limit>0){var interval,f,self=input;$(this).focus(function(){interval=window.setInterval(substring,100)}),$(this).bind("keyup keypress blur change",function(){clearInterval(interval),substring()}),substringFunction="function substring(){ var val = $(self).val();var length = val.length;if(length > options.limit){$(self).val($(self).val().substring(0,options.limit));}","undefined"!=typeof $(options.counter)&&(substringFunction+="if($(options.counter).html() != options.limit - length){$(options.counter).html((options.limit - length<=0)?'0':options.limit - length);}"),substringFunction+="}",eval(substringFunction),substring()}return options.allow=s.join("|"),regex=new RegExp(options.allow,"gi"),ch=(options.ichars+options.nchars).replace(regex,""),input.keypress(function(n){var i=String.fromCharCode(n.charCode?n.charCode:n.which);-1==ch.indexOf(i)||n.ctrlKey||n.preventDefault()}),input.blur(function(){var n=input.val(),i=0;for(i;i<n.length;i++)if(-1!=ch.indexOf(n[i]))return input.val(""),!1;return!1}),input},$.fn.numeric=function(n){var i="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzążśźćłóę",t=i.toUpperCase();return this.each(function(){$(this).alphanumeric($.extend({nchars:i+t},n))})},$.fn.alpha=function(n){var i="1234567890";return this.each(function(){$(this).alphanumeric($.extend({nchars:i},n))})}}(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

  // if numeric function is present then define some classes
  if (typeof $.fn.numeric == "function") {
    $(".numeric").numeric();
  }

  $(".openWindow").click(function() {

    var form = `
        <form method="post">
            <label for="onlynumbers">Input with numbers:</label>
           <input type="text" id="onlynumbers" name="onlynumbers" value="" class="numeric" required />
        </form>
    `;

    var $dialog = $("<div></div>").html(form).dialog({
      height: 100,
      width: 400,
      title: 'Here is a problem'
    });
    $dialog.dialog("open");

  });

});
```

```css
#layout {
  padding: 25px;
}
#layout form {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.4/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>

<div id="layout">
  <p>Look: this input accept only numbers.</p>
  <form method="post">
    <label for="onlynumbers">Input with numbers:</label>
    <input type="text" id="onlynumbers" name="onlynumbers" value="" class="numeric" required />
  </form>

  <button type="button" class="openWindow">Open dialog window</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `$(".numeric").numeric();` code is called only once, before the dialog box is even created.

So, this code should work:

```
        $(".openWindow").click(function(){

            var form = `
                <form method="post">
                    <label for="onlynumbers">Input with numbers:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="onlynumbers" name="onlynumbers" value="" class="numeric" required />
                </form>
            `;

            var $dialog = $("<div></div>").html(form).dialog({ height: 100, width: 400, title: 'Here is a problem'});
            $(".numeric").numeric();
            $dialog.dialog("open");

        });
```

Comment: Yes, of course it works. But is there any chance to define it "more global"? "numeric" class will not be the only class that I want to use in dialog window.

Comment: You could do something such as `$dialog.find("input[type=text]").numeric();`

Comment: I have to then figure out some other way. Some fields are only numbers, some are text, etc. I need to use all functions that I have, I will not double them. But thanks for help and interest.

Comment: Why don't you just make all inputs that only allow numbers have the class of "numeric", inputs that allow text have the class of "text", etc?